# Symfony2 ManyToMany embedded forms

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, entity-relationship

I have a Post and Tag entity in my application, and I need many to many association between them. I think I managed it right, but not enirely sure. Here are my entities:

Post:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="posts")
*/
class Post
{
    ( ... )

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostTag", mappedBy="post_id")
    */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ( ... )
}
```

Tag:

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tagname", unique=true, type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $tagname;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostTag", mappedBy="tag_id")
     */
    private $posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ( ... )
}
```

I also created a PostTag entity to store these relations:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="post_tags")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class PostTag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tag_id;

    ( ... )
}
```

Of course all 3 with appropriate getters/setters. Are the relations okay this way?

I believe I have it right, but now I'm struggling to make an embedded form for the Post entity. What I need is, to create a tags field in the PostType, where one could type in tags which are saved in the tags table and the id of both the newly created tag and post in the post_tags table. I also want the already saved tags to be pickable in another field, that's why I have the entities build this way.

I tried to write this, but got really confused with bad codes, so I don't even try to copy what I had. Can someone briefly enlighten me how should I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need intermediary entity between `Post` and `Tag`. I myself struggled to get it working a few months back, but after carefully reading [Many-To-Many, Unidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional), I managed to do it.

The point is that you don't create `Many-To-One` and `One-To-Many` relations but a single `Many-To-Many`.

Regarding the embedded forms, once you establish `Many-To-Many` relation between `Post` and `Tag` you'll need to use `collection` field form type. Basically, you'll be saying: "OK, I have a form that has fields of `Post` which can have **many** `Tags`.

Of course, I would suggest you try managing data manually (persist, update, delete) before trying to make it work with forms. If you have an error in your model it'll be much more difficult to locate the source of a problem, as forms themselves can be tricky.

Official Symfony docs have a great [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) on this, although, I must say, it's a little overwhelming for a Symfony beginner as I was in a time of reading it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem is, I really don't want to make a real many-to-many relation. I can't add any fields or formatting to that table if I do that, and I just really don't like that. Even the Doctrine docs which you linked says that it's better practice to create an intermediary entity with one-to-many, many-to-one relations among the 3 entities. Thanks for the form collections tips!

Comment: I went with this solution in the end.